# `zfs replace` keeps giving write errors with new drives & different SATA cables

Tags: raid, zfs

I replaced a failing hard drive (increasing error counts in SMART, read/write/checksum errors in `zpool status`) in a ZFS raidz1 pool with a new one by running `zfs offline` and `zfs replace`. Resilvering started shortly, but keeps giving me write errors (please see below). When these resilvering processes eventually finished, the pool would remain in DEGRADED stated. If I `zpool clear` the errors or reboot, another resilvering process would start automatically, but giving a potentially different number of write errors.

SMART shows no error for this new drive. I also tried a different new drive (bought two replacements) and swapping SATA cables. It's always this vdev being replaced (with either drive) giving the write errors during resilvering. This made me suspect that the ZFS pool is somehow compromised, but it continues to run and is able to `zfs send` every night.

What's the right way to troubleshoot and resolve this issue (e.g., like `zfs scrub` a DEGRADED pool with just three of the four drives, since `zfs replace` cannot complete without errors)? I do have backups made by `zfs send/receive` which are hopefully good copies (does ZFS checksum received streams?).

```
  pool: space
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Fri Nov  3 09:56:59 2023
        2.92T scanned at 594M/s, 2.63T issued at 536M/s, 5.90T total
        669G resilvered, 44.59% done, 01:46:40 to go
config:

        NAME                                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        space                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz1-0                               DEGRADED     0     0     0
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_ZZZZ1111      ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_ZZZZ2222      ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
            replacing-2                          UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
              13284017409215481231               OFFLINE      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F12QMZ-part1
              ata-ST18000NM003D-3DL103_YYYY1111  FAULTED      0 4.38K     0  too many errors  (resilvering)
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_ZZZZ4444      ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
```

**EDIT**: I'm seeing these errors in `dmesg`:

```
[19561.708059] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#226 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=31s
[19561.708063] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#226 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[19561.708067] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#226 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[19561.708070] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#226 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 68 f4 ff 40 00 00 00 53 00 00
[19561.708073] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1760886592 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x700 phys_seg 83 prio class 0
```

Comment: Uhm so basically you think that it has something to do with the software while one replacement drive works perfectly and the other does not?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. I meant no other vdevs in the pool gave any errors, but the vdev being replaced is giving the write errors with both new drives.

Comment: Could it be the SATA port? Have you tried another one?

Comment: Yes, I swapped the SATA and power cables of this drive with another drive in the zpool. Errors stayed with the vdev being resilvered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some hints from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/17n61dg/comment/k7sk403/), this may be a [software/firmware bug](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10094) that the Seagate Exos X20 ST18000NM003D 18TB drive cannot use 512B sectors on ThinkStation S30 / Ubuntu 22.04 5.15.0-88-generic. I ended up destroying the pool and recreating it using 4K sectors and the errors have not returned.